# Query function not pulling data after Col19

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Goal:**
I'm trying to pull columns of data with the Query function and I'm not using anything conditions so it shouldn't be complicated.

**Current function setup:**

```html
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1QUZ-ljkXNOvtnPg-a2FqM2PhYUdt_zX5gMLtB6GcFdc","Status!$A$16:$S"),"SELECT Col2, Col7, Col9, Col10, Col15, Col16, Col17, Col18, Col19, Col20",1)
```

**Issue:**
I was able to pull data for each column until I included the 20th column which is Column T. The error was a #VALUE! with the message as: "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col20."

I also tried change the code to the following, thinking that I may be selecting too many columns, however I'm still getting the same error: "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col20."

```html
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1QUZ-ljkXNOvtnPg-a2FqM2PhYUdt_zX5gMLtB6GcFdc","Status!$A$16:$S"),"SELECT Col2, Col7, Col9, Col20",1)
```

Something that I also noticed was that when I changed the query to "SELECT *" then I was only able to pull data up to the 19th column, so I'm assuming that there's a limitation when using the IMPORTRANGE function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

Column `20` is column `T` but your range stops at column `S`. If you need to query column `20` you need to expand your range up to column `T`: `"Status!$A$16:$T"`

**Solution:**

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1QUZ-ljkXNOvtnPg-a2FqM2PhYUdt_zX5gMLtB6GcFdc","Status!$A$16:$T"),"SELECT Col2, Col7, Col9, Col10, Col15, Col16, Col17, Col18, Col19, Col20",1)
```

Comment: OMG. I'm so sorry for asking such a simple question. This is totally my mistake... Thank you for pointing it out.